# ListView different background each item

Tags: android, colors, android-listview, background-color

im trying to make a list to show status of some activities, to show if the activity finish well... not so well or if it fails something like this

*****mockup*************
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/002qo.png/

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to set background for a list view item, I add a attribute to the data I send to the list adapter which is an integer holding values 1,2 or 3.

In the adapter code, in the getView method I check for the attribute value and set the background color of the view accordingly. Sort of like

```
if(status == 1){
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
} else if(statis == 2){
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
}
```